# Why can't I copy .CR2 files using shutil?

Tags: python, shutil

```
import os
import shutil
os.chdir('C:\\')

dir_src = ('C:\\Users\\Tibi\\Desktop\\New Folder\\New Folder')
dir_dst = ('D:\\test')


for folder in os.walk(dir_src):
    print(folder)
    for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
        if filename.endswith('.CR2'):
            shutil.copy(dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
        print(filename)
```

Note that the file causing it to quit is one of the files I want to copy to the test folder. I tried using other file types and they don't work either.

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "copyfiletree.py", line 14, in <module>
    shutil.copy(dir_src + filename, dir_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Tibi\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 235, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Tibi\Anaconda3\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\New FolderIMG_5221.CR2'
```

I think I should mention that my computer is infected with Spora ransomware (however, these files are not encrypted).

NEW CODE I'M TRYING TO USE:

```
import os
import shutil
#os.chdir('C:\\')

dir_src = ('D:\\Users\\Tibi\\Pictures')
dir_dst = ('D:\\test')

#while True:
#    try:
#        for folder in os.walk(dir_src):
#            print(folder)
#            for filename in os.listdir(dir_src):
#                if filename.endswith('.CR2'):
#                    shutil.copy(dir_src + '\\' + filename, dir_dst)
#                print(filename)
#    except UnicodeEncodeError:
#        print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>File %s was Skipped!<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" %filename)
import pathlib
import glob

dir_src = pathlib.Path(r'D:\\Users\\Tibi\\Pictures//Move')
dir_dst = pathlib.Path(r'D:\test')

for file in dir_src.rglob('*.mp4'):
    shutil.copy(str(file), str(dir_dst / file.name))
    print("Current File is: %s" % file)
```

Comment: `dir_src + filename` doesn't have a path separator like "\" between them.

Comment: With raw strings, it should be `r'D:\Users\Tibi\Pictures\Move'` but it shouldn't make a difference.  Also note that `'*.mp4'` will not match `file.MP4`, you would need `'*.[Mm][Pp]4'` if you want to ignore case.

Answer (score 2):

In general, don't make paths using `+`.  Use `os.path.join` which is smarter:

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(dir_src, filename), dir_dst)
```

This will give you `C:\...\folder\file` instead of `C:\...\folderfile`.

Alternatively, you can use `pathlib`:

```
import pathlib
import shutil

dir_src = pathlib.Path(r'C:\Users\Tibi\Desktop\New Folder\New Folder')
dir_dst = pathlib.Path(r'D:\test')

for file in dir_src.rglob('*.CR2'):
    shutil.copy(str(file), str(dir_dst / file.name))
```

If you need to match regardless of case, use this `'*.[Cc][Rr]2'` instead of `'*.CR2'`.

Comment: If I take away the other folders and start at 'C:\Users', will it run in the subfolders too?

Comment: Yes, that's what `rglob()` does.  It gives you all of the files in all of the subfolders which match the pattern.

Comment: I still don't know much about Python, let alone rglob() and pathlib. It's not doing what I need it to do and I can't quite figure it out.  I have about a dozen subfolders that have this file type in there and it's no doing anything.  I add print("Current File is: %s" % file) and there is still no output nor any changes to the destination folder. I also changed tho source to another directory ('D:\\Users\\Tibi\\Pictures') with the files in subfolders of the Pictures folder.

Comment: "It's not doing what I need it to do" is unfortunately not enough information.  The next questions are always going to be "What do you need it to do?" and "What is it actually doing?" and "What is the code?"

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I need to take all my .CR2 files from various subfolders and copy them over to a new folder.  The code that you gave me in the answer is the code that I'm trying to use and it does nothing.  The pointer blinks for a couple seconds and the file stops running with no output and no changes in the destination folder.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting.  I tested the program on my computer and it seems to work correctly.  Is it possible that `.CR2` is incorrectly capitalized?

Comment: I double checked and it is not. It's a RAW image file, could that have anything to do with it?  I imagine that it wouldn't, but I could be wrong.

Comment: It's still just a file.  I suspect there is a wrong path somewhere in the code, I don't really have any other explanation.

Comment: I will update the question to reflect my exact code that I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Add a path separator between to prevent `C:\\New FolderIMG_5221.CR2` nonexistant file. Change this:

```
dir_src + filename
```

to this:

```
dir_src + '\\' + filename
```

or this for a more generic solution that might not be on Windows:

```
dir_src + os.path.sep + filename
```

Comment: Any idea why it throws a UnicodEncodeError?  I threw in an exception and it works, but I still have a lot to learn.  Watching this run, I realized that it is just cycling through just a few folders.  How can I make it open each folder and scan each one for the .CR2 files?